# HTTPS resource links in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, ssl, https, django-rest-framework

I would like to get https links for resources instead of the current http links.

Example currently I get something like this:
http://10.16.18.46:9000/media/tds_data/2020/2/1/6328/cat.12233.jpg

what should I change in the get request in views.py

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    files = Files.objects.all()
    serializer = FilesSerializer(files, many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: SSL and https is not configured inside django.  Its the responsibility of nginx, apache, or whatever WSGI interface you are deploying on.

Comment: @Jason answerd the question, but I will add that using a hyperlinked resource will add your current URL to the fetcheted resource, at my local development I get http but at production server I get https because of the host itself.